# GTK# 2.12.30 Toolbar broken in windows

Tags: c#, monodevelop, toolbar, gtk#

I just updated to GTK# 2.12.30 from 2.12.26 on Windows. Now the toolbar of my application is really thin and looks strange. Here a screenshot:
[image: Broken toolbar]

In designer it looks like this:

[image: Designer view]

Has anybody the same problem and an idea, why this happens? Seems to be a windows only problem, on linux the toolbar is there.
The toolbar's size is "system-default", I already tried changing this, but this doesn't change anything.
Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like the icon bug that happens to other widgets like the button.

Comment: So is this a known bug? Do you know, where the bug happens? I ask because I would like to know, if I have to change anything in the project or just wait for the bugfix.

Comment: I would file a bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com). If you can provide a small sample app with the problem and attach that to the bug report.

Comment: I added a bug now: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40730